# Unserialsed Array giving the weirdest results

Tags: php, arrays

I've a really odd issue today. I've got a serialised array that looks like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:7:"Perfect";i:1;s:10:"jawel hoor";i:2;s:14:"Ach jawohl joh";i:3;s:2:"Ja";}
```

Then after I execute this code:

```
include '../../database/connect.php';   
Class Calc {
    function getPrice($id) {
        $Db = new Db();
        $sth = $Db->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = :id");
        $sth->execute(array(':id'=>$id));


        $are_you_serial = $sth->fetchAll();
        foreach($are_you_serial as $row) {
            $serialised = $row['reply_array'];
            $product_id = $row['product_id'];
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        }
        $array = unserialize($serialised);
        foreach($array as $row) {
            echo $row[1];
        }

    }
}
$calc = new Calc();
$calc->getPrice(11);
```

eaca comes out. When I call row 0 PjAJ comes out.
When I call row 2 this seems to be the error:

```
rwh
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in index.php on line 29
```

This is what the array looks like if I just print_r the $array:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Perfect
   [1] => jawel hoor
   [2] => Ach jawohl joh
   [3] => Ja
)
```

I can also call $array[0] and it'll show the right things but once I put it in the foreach it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: `foreach($array as $row) {
            echo $row[1];
        }` should surely be `foreach($array as $row) {
            echo $row;
        }`

Comment: you're querying for what could (probably) only ever be one row of data. why are you using a fetchAll() and a loop for a single record? why not just `$row = $sth->fetch()`?

Comment: Because I also need the user_id and product_id @MarcB
//EDIT: nvm i'm stupid thanks for that too :P

Comment: Hey @MarkBaker that seems to work. :O But than why can't I use $row[key]? I thought that should just be possible in a foreach?

Comment: `$row` is the string __value__ of an __individual array element__ from `$array`, not an array itself

Comment: @user2879055 Maybe it helps when you read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php To see/understand how a foreach loop works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `foreach` keeps reassigning the variables, so `$serialised` (should be `$serialized` BTW) will only ever hold the value of the last row by the time you're actually calling `unserialize`. I'll add what I think you want bellow, but for now, some more details on why you're getting the *"weird"* or unexpected output:

A little info on how to read the PHP serialized format:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:7:"Perfect";i:1;s:10:"jawel hoor";...
```

- `a:4:{`: What follows is an array, containing 4 key-value pairs
- `i:0;`: An integer, value 0. Because this is part of an array, all odd values are keys, even values are values, so the first index of the array is 0
- `s:7:"Perfect";`: A string, 7 chars long, and the string itself is *"Perfect"* (without the quotes)

Same applies to objects that are serialized:

```
O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:3:"bar";i:123;s:3:"foo";i:456;}
```

- `o:8:"stdClass":2:{`: An object, the class name of which is 8 chars long (`stdClass`), with 2 properties set
- `s:3:"bar";i:123;`: The property name is a 3-char long string (*"bar"*), its value is an int (*123*)
- `s:3:"foo";i:456;`: 3-char long property (*"foo"*) with value *456*
- `}`: End of serialized object

Knowing this, you should be able to work out that what you're doing with the data after you've unserialized, ie this:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo $row[1];
}
```

Is just all shades of wrong, the value of `$row` will be a string, and getting an index/offset of a string is possible (preferably using the `{}` notation, as in `$row{1}`), but it'll return the *character* at offset `n`, where `n` is the digit/key between brackets. Strings are, like arrays, zero-indexed BTW, so `$string = 'foo'; echo $string{0};` will echo *"f"*, and `echo $string{1};` will echo *"o"*.

What you want, then is to write:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo $row;
}
```

or shorter:

```
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $array);//PHP_EOL to add linebreaks between the strings
```

Like I said at the beginning, you're only really processing the very last serialized value, what you actually want is probably something more like this:

```
$unserialized = [];
foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $row) {
    //add unserialized values to an array
    $unserialized[] = unserialize($row['reply_array']);
}
//$unserialized is now an array of arrays
foreach ($unserialized as $rowNr => $array) {
    echo 'Row #', $rowNr+1, ': ', PHP_EOL,
        implode(PHP_EOL, $array);
}
```

That ought to get you started...